# What are the flags being flown by this column of Russian tanks?

Tags: russian-federation, military, flag

I just saw [this video of Russian tanks on a video on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Archer83Able/status/1513542757998112768).

I can see four different flags flown by the soldiers but I can't make out what they are apart from the last one which just looks like the flag of Russia. I tried to screenshot them as best as I could but what are they and what does the text on them say?

[image]

Comment: Is flag identification on topic? If it is can you post an image of the flags rather than a video?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, because in this case it's a type of political messaging. See also my meta answer [on this question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4729).

Comment: I saw other questions on identifying flags i hope that this is okay :) I tried to post an image but it wouldn't let me, i think its showing now?

Comment: Well I recognize the last one...

Comment: Well the audio says "look, our flag, imperial" and "marine/naval infantry".

Comment: @Fizz thanks thats really useful do u know if the dudes in the car are speaking russian or ukranian

Comment: I'm not an expert on accents in the region (nor a native speaker of either Russia or Ukrainian).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first flag shown is the double-headed eagle from the [Coat of Arms of the Russian Empire](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Russian_Empire.svg) imposed on the [Empire's black/yellow/white tricolour](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_the_Russian_Empire_(black-yellow-white).svg). The flag also includes the motto "Мы - русские / С нами Бог", - roughly  "We are Russian / God is with us".

[image]
 <sub>Image from [RusAtribut](https://rusatribut.ru/products/flag-imperskij-my-russkie-s-nami-bog)</sub>

The second flag is another unofficial one, it appears to be an alteration of the [old flag of the Russian Naval Infantry](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_the_Russian_Naval_Infantry_(1992%E2%80%932020).jpg), which was changed in 2020. The flag's emblem has been replaced with a skull wearing the Naval Infantry beret imposed on two crossed anchors, with the motto "Где мы - там победа" - "Where we are, there is victory". The text on the top is "Морская пехота", Russian for Naval Infantry.

[image]
 <sub>Image from [RusAtribut](https://rusatribut.ru/products/flag-morskaya-pehota-cherep)</sub>

The third, fourth and fifth flags are all the same - the [ensign of the Russian Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensign_of_the_Russian_Navy), and you've already identified the final flag as the flag of the Russian Federation.

Comment: Are these official unit colours? If so which units do they correspond to? Or are they irregular designs?

Comment: Is _С нами Бог_ a statement of fact or a prayer?  If the latter, it should be translated as "God be with us."

Comment: @CharlieEvans: I checked the 5 or so Russia  naval infantry brigades that have their badges on Wikipedia, but it corresponds to none of those. The most grizzly official one has black bear grabbing the globe.

Comment: @phoog, a statement. Very much the same as [Gott mit uns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gott_mit_uns).

Comment: @CharlieEvans the black-yellow-white (black-gold-white) flag is not official; it's often used by nationalist and monarchist groups in Russia.

Comment: @Fizz It's possible these are battalion colours (if Russian battalions even have them, I don't know). I don't think the "grizzly" nature of the second design indicates it is unofficial. For example, USAF squadrons and USMC reconnaissance battalions seem to have a particular penchant for skulls in their official insignia.

Comment: @CharlieEvans: I know of the US practice, but it seems that the official Russian insignia are all about wild animals and no skulls.

Comment: @mustaccio Well, today I am surprised to learn that there are some prominent Russian politicians who advocate the restoration of the Romanov dynasty!

Comment: I think I'd have worried the image of a skull wearing their uniform might give the impression that where they are, there is victory ... for someone else. :)

Answer (score 13):

The black yellow white flag is [First official State Flag of the Russian Empire and Flag for "Celebrations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_flags#Historical_state_flags_of_Russia). The logo on that first flag is an imperial standard, as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_flags#Historical_standards_of_Russia).

The White flags with the blue cross seem to be navy flags. [Wikipedia lists it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_flags#Banners_of_the_Armed_Forces_of_the_Russian_Federation) as the *Banner of the Russian Navy* with the description:

> The ensign of the Russian Navy is used as the banner of the Russian Navy. On December 29, 2000, Russian President Vladimir Putin signed a federal law making the naval ensign of the Russian navy the official banner of the Russian Navy.

The last flag seems to be the white blue red which is [the flag of the Russian Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_flags#Flag_of_the_Russian_Federation).

I'm not sure about the logos on the navy flags (yet).